# When using Twitter OAuth with TweetSharp I keep getting asked to authorize my app every time a user wants to log in

Tags: twitter, web, oauth, tweetsharp

I'm trying to implement OAuth with twitter so my users can log into my site using their Twitter IDs. For this I am using the TweetSharp library. Following the examples they have I wrote the following code which seems to work.

```
        public ActionResult Login(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
        {
            var service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            if (oauth_token == null)
            {
                var requestToken = service.GetRequestToken(Request.Url.ToString());
                var uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
                return new RedirectResult(uri.ToString(), false);
            }
            else
            {
                var requestToken = new OAuthRequestToken { Token = oauth_token };
                OAuthAccessToken accessToken = service.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);

                service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
                TwitterUser user = service.VerifyCredentials(new VerifyCredentialsOptions());
                TempData["response"] = string.Format("Your username is {0}", user.ScreenName);
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Success()
        {
            ViewBag.Response = TempData["response"];
            return View();
        }
```

However, there is a problem. Every time the user logs into the system twitter asks them to authorize the application even though they have done it before. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I have also implemented OAuth with Facebook and Google and I don't need to authorize the application every time I want to log into the system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not as far as I'm aware. Twitter uses OAuth 1.1 rather than OAuth 2.0 like Facebook and Google, so there is a manual step in the middle in which users are asked to authorise the application even though they have done already. I'm having exactly the same issue and it appears to be something we have to live with.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a slightly older app I was trying to resurrect. I noticed that the problem went away when I selected "Sign in with Twitter" in my app settings at http://dev.twitter.com/apps.